# MyBatisCursorItemReader error when using multithreads

Tags: spring-batch, mybatis

I'm using spring batch (version 4.2.1) with MyBatisCursorItemReader to load data from MySql. To improve the performance, I'm trying to use multithread by ThreadPoolTaskExecutor as the thread pool. When there is a single thread is ok but when set the thread pool large than 1 thread, the MyBatisCursorItemReader throw exception as below:

```
org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 'xxx' from result set.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:83)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.applyAutomaticMappings(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:521)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:402)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:354)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:328)
    at org.apache.ibatis.cursor.defaults.DefaultCursor.fetchNextObjectFromDatabase(DefaultCursor.java:141)
    at org.apache.ibatis.cursor.defaults.DefaultCursor.fetchNextUsingRowBound(DefaultCursor.java:125)
    at org.apache.ibatis.cursor.defaults.DefaultCursor$CursorIterator.hasNext(DefaultCursor.java:197)
    at org.mybatis.spring.batch.MyBatisCursorItemReader.doRead(MyBatisCursorItemReader.java:55)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:545)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:948)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getTimestamp(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.DateTypeHandler.getNullableResult(DateTypeHandler.java:39)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.DateTypeHandler.getNullableResult(DateTypeHandler.java:28)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:81)
```

Is there anything wrong or the MyBatisCursorItemReader not support multithread?

Comment: `MyBatisCursorItemReader` is a subclass of [`AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html) and the doc says "Subclasses are inherently not thread-safe".

Comment: tks, and I rewritten it @ave